# Salesforce integration with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, salesforce, force.com

I am creating an application using ASP.NET MVC which has to integrate with salesforce.

I have created a developer account and also a trial account for Salesforce. Using my developer account I am able to achieve my desired outcome however when using my trial salesforce account I get this error 
"The REST API is not enabled for this Organization."

I have also used another developer account of my mate it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Trail Edition (i.e. Professional Edition). Trail Edition doesn't include API access. If you want to try out api please use [Developer Edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup). Trial Edition expires after 30 days, but DE account doesn't expire.

Here is the list of [salesforce editions with api access](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005140&language=en_US&type=1).
​